# Correct usage of jQuery toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

```
$('#btn2').toggle(
    function () {
        $('#btn2').text('show');
    },
    function () {
        $('#btn2').text('hide');                
    }
)
```

This does not work on my computer (on any browser). Could this be due to a change in the method between jQuery versions?

Comment: If you want to check if something is (still) supported, you check [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). It has very good detail about appropriate usage, as well as the version in which features were added/removed. That should always be your first stop, and always do that before asking a question SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUtU6/)

[This functionality of `.toggle` was removed in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

So this [wont work](http://jsfiddle.net/pUtU6/1/) for jQuery 1.9 or later..

See one alternative [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pUtU6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Per your updated feature request, to simply alternate between two inner text values:

```
$('#btn2').click(function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text()=='show'? 'hide':'show' );
});
```

---

That is not one of the signatures of [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle). To use its hide/show capabilities, do this `$(elem).toggle()` (and obviously if the button is hidden it can't say 'show', so presumably you're toggling something else):

```
$(elem).toggle();
$('#btn2').text( $(elem).is(':visible') ? 'hide' : 'show' );
```

Comment: sorry but I just want the text (value) on the button change from 'show' to 'hide', 'hide' to 'show'…. once it is clicked. again and again

Comment: @user2049259 Note: if you use `<button></button>`, use `text`, but if you use `<input type='button' />` use `val`. Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TxXVB/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/W9JCR/

```
$('#btn2').click(function () {
   ($(this).text()=='show') ? $(this).text('hide') : $(this).text('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's still supported. I think the problem with your code is that you've used `text()`. Use `val()`

```
$('#btn2').toggle(function () {
    $('#btn2').val('show');
    },function () {
        $('#btn2').val('hide');                
});
```